# c# progress bar starting at old value on second run

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

So I have a quick file mover program and it works fine and the progress bar show the right percentage while working but when i run it a second time. The progress bar starts at the last value. Even though I start by updating the progressbar1.value = 0;
Only way to make the progressbar re-start at zero is to close the program and start it again

```
   private void button_move_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //neither updating the Value to 0 or ReportProgress to 0 worked
            //progressbar1.Value = 0;
            //worker.ReportProgress(0);

            moveFiles(sender, e, dirFiless);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error trying to Move files: " + ex);
        }
    }
    private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage - 1;
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            progressbar1.Value = 0;
            return;
    }

    //this works and the progress bar gets updated incrementally 
    public void moveFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, string[] dirFiles)  
    {
        totalFiles = dirFiles.Length;
        foreach (string file in dirFiles)
        {
               filecount++;
               percentage = (int)((filecount * 100) / totalFiles);
               worker.ReportProgress(percentage);
               //move file
        }
        worker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
```

Comment: Where are all your member fields, e.g. do you reset `filecount` as I only see incrementing it in your code. In addition it would be helpful to clean it a bit up as currently there is a lot of noise in the code for the question you ask :)
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you @DAXaholic I just cleaned my code a bit so its easier to read. And Yes i did not reset the filecount. (facepalm) That is why it kept starting at its old value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you resetting your `filecount` variable back to 0?  In the code you posted it appears that it just keeps counting up with each run which would cause the progress bar to jump back up even after you previously set it back to 0.

Comment: Definitely not. very rookie mistake. I did not clear the filecount at the end of the process. Thank You!!